# Stop images from shaking page on resizing

Tags: html, css

I have several images that are in a line that will resize on hover so that the user knows that the image is being selected. The problem is that when you move from one image to the next, all the rest of the images move downwards. Additionally, when moving quickly from one image to the next, the screen appears to shake. How can I fix this?

```css
img{
  margin:10px;
}
img:hover{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sgqsn618/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix this, add `vertical-align: top` to your images. Also, to prevent the screen from looking so shaky, add a transition to your images.

```css
img{
    margin:10px;
    vertical-align: top;
    transition: all 200ms ease;
}
img:hover{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
<img src="https://www.thegamecrafter.com/printable-icon/SmallSquareMat.png" width="70" height="70" />
```

Comment: This is working really great for single row images, but not so much when there are multiple rows. Any help there?

Comment: @TwoShorts_ Sorry, your question didn't specify that you were intending to do multiple rows. Give me a second and I will work up a solution.

Comment: @TwoShorts_ Is this example closer to what you had in mind? http://jsfiddle.net/sgqsn618/2/